# How to resample/aggregate based on a duration in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have data in this format:

```
start | end | hours
[date]|[date]| integer
```

I'd like to resample this so that I end up with one-row-per day, and with `hours` evenly divided across as many days fit between `start` and `end`.

I feel like this should be possible with resample/aggregate in pandas, but despite having looked at the docs for those functions am not quite sure what the syntax would be. Is this possible/easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `apply` and `explode`, then a `groupby`.

I made a fake dataset which hopefully is representative of what you're asking:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'start': {0: '2021-01-01',  1: '2021-01-02',  2: '2021-01-03',
  3: '2021-01-04',  4: '2021-01-05'},
 'end': {0: '2021-01-06',  1: '2021-01-03',  2: '2021-01-08',
  3: '2021-01-04',  4: '2021-01-06'},
 'hours': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 15, 3: 14, 4: 13}}
)
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

print(df)
       start        end  hours
0 2021-01-01 2021-01-06      8
1 2021-01-02 2021-01-03      9
2 2021-01-03 2021-01-08     15
3 2021-01-04 2021-01-04     14
4 2021-01-05 2021-01-06     13
```

Build an series of indexes based on your date ranges:

```
idx = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start'], x['end']), axis=1)
```

Explode it into rows, and join it to the original dataframe on the original integer index:

```
new_df = idx.explode().to_frame('date').join(df[['hours']])
```

Then you can directly calculate the hours per day:

```
new_df['hours_spread'] = new_df['hours']/new_df.groupby(level=0).size()

print(new_df)
        date  hours  hours_spread
0 2021-01-01      8      1.333333
0 2021-01-02      8      1.333333
0 2021-01-03      8      1.333333
0 2021-01-04      8      1.333333
0 2021-01-05      8      1.333333
0 2021-01-06      8      1.333333
1 2021-01-02      9      4.500000
1 2021-01-03      9      4.500000
2 2021-01-03     15      2.500000
2 2021-01-04     15      2.500000
2 2021-01-05     15      2.500000
2 2021-01-06     15      2.500000
2 2021-01-07     15      2.500000
2 2021-01-08     15      2.500000
3 2021-01-04     14     14.000000
4 2021-01-05     13      6.500000
4 2021-01-06     13      6.500000
```

Comment: hey - thanks this is great and does solve the problem nicely.